# "Agent JAR not found or no Agent-Class attribute",but success when invoke quickly after the java process start

Tags: java, spring-boot, jvm, javaagents

Here is the position,when i use java agent to attach a running java project,it failed.It reported "Agent JAR not found or no Agent-Class attribute".
I know this is not the reason of my agent because it successed when i quickly restart the java project and attach the agent to the project as soon as possible.But when i attached after the seconds when the java project started,it got "Agent JAR not found or no Agent-Class attribute" error.

agentmain code:

```
package org.test;
public class test{
    public static void agentmain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) throws IOException, UnmodifiableClassException, IllegalClassFormatException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException       {
        Class[] classes = inst.getAllLoadedClasses();
        for (Class aClass : classes) {
            if (aClass.getName().equals(DDDFFEE.editClassName)){
                inst.addTransformer(new DDDFFEE(),true);
                inst.retransformClasses(aClass);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Agent-Class: org.test.test
Can-Redefine-Classes: true
Can-Retransform-Classes: true
```

The java project is a spring boot web application,and i don't konw why it became like this.

How to attach the running java process whenever the java project start?

I tried lots of times,and check the environments,the java version is the same,the pid file exists,but it worked only when i attach the java process when it started in 1 second,how to solve this?

Comment: If you want to have the agent always present when the program start, you should not attach at a later time at all, but use [the `-javaagent` option and define a `premain` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html#starting-an-agent-from-the-command-line-interface-heading). But note that your code will fail if the class you’re searching for has not been loaded yet. Just call `inst.addTransformer(new DDDFFEE(), true);` unconditionally. You have to check the name in `transform` (which is called on every class load) anyway.

Comment: In addition to what @Holger said, you will also need a `Premain-Class` manifest attribute.